# Unable to access Node on Mac - command not found

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal

I am getting the following response when I try to access node from terminal

> node:command not found

I researched and found that I have to set PATH. I tried the following:

> export PATH="/usr/local/bin/node:$PATH">> ~/.profile

It runs (I assume since the terminal doesn't return anything). But when I echo the path I get the following response

> export PATH=/usr/local/bin/node:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/arihantjain/NVPACK/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Users/arihantjain/NVPACK/android-sdk-macosx/tools:/Users/arihantjain/NVPACK/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin

Clearly, I think the path isn't getting set. How can I do that? If not, is there a way to change the default installation directory of node. I used the .pkg installer to install Node.

Comment: The `.pkg` installer installs the executable in `/usr/local/bin` (unless you changed the installation location while running the installer), which is already in your `$PATH`, so it doesn't really make sense that the executable can't be found.

Comment: Start a new terminal. At worst, reboot and try again (you REALLY don't need to reboot, the reboot is only a brute-force way to get YOU to start a new terminal, you don't even need to start a new terminal, that is again a brute-force way to get you to start a new shell). Once you see it working google and read up on how `.profile` and `.bashrc` works.

Comment: Somehow the problem wasn't the path. Looks like node wasn't installed at all. I installed it again using brew and it worked totally fine. The installed gave me a notification saying that node has been installed when I used .pkg installer. Weird